# How do I properly set tcp_keepalives with flyway connections?

Tags: flyway

**How do I get the connections made with flyway to postgres to use keepalives ?**

I've tried appending ?tcpKeepAlive=true to the URL, that doesn't seem to work. *(the url output while using the cli seems to omit that this is part of the URL, trying to set it as a jdbc.property. only throws an error)*

what am I missing ?

note: my migration works with psql over tcp to a remote host without issue, but flyways dies reporting the connection as closed after ~ 10 minutes.

Comment: Looking at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html the parameter should be `tcpKeepAlive=true` not `tcpKeepAlives`

Comment: @PhilipLiddell I had typo'd it in the post, I was using: tcpKeepAlive and it's not functional as reported. but good eye on seeing that.